# Open office writer crashed when inserting table using java POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to insert table using apache-poi in .docx format using open office..But the file is crashed every time i open the file

```
      XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C://create_table.docx"));

      //create table
      XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

      //create first row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
      tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
      tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
      tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");

      //create second row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
      tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
      tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
      tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");

      //create third row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();
      tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
      tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
      tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");

      document.write(out);
      out.close();
      System.out.println("create_table.docx written successully");
   }
```

Comment: Is going to be hard to help you if you don't provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)...

Comment: please provide the error capture or exceptions

Comment: there's no error or exception sir..my code is run successfuly and when i open the file using open office writer it is crashed

Answer (score 0):

Libreoffice/Openoffice needs a table grid to accept the column widths.

This should work:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordTable {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

      //create table
      XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

      //create first row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
      tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
      tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
      tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");

  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the 3 columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //values are in unit twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch)
  //first column = 2 inches width
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
  //other columns (2 in this case) also each 2 inches width
  for (int col = 1 ; col < 3; col++) {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
  }

      //create second row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
      tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
      tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
      tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");

      //create third row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();
      tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
      tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
      tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTable.docx"));
  document.close();

  System.out.println("CreateWordTable written successully");
 }
}
```

Btw.: Please always have at least one paragraph before and after the table. Else it is really impossible to get the cursor outside the table.