# Apache POI creating tables issue

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_tables.htm for creating tables using `Apache POI`. But for some unknown reason the table is not generating correctly. I'm getting this:

[image]

Comment: you need to specify cell width

Comment: Do I have to? I'm literally just copying and pasting the code from tutorials point, so I'd imagine there would be some sort of default value set for cell width if not specified. And it doesn't look like a table is even getting created.

Comment: open created file in browser

Comment: Which `apache poi`version is used? Which `Microsoft Word`version is used?

Comment: I'm using 3.16. I don't have Microsoft Word on my mac, I'm opening the docx files in Pages and Open Office.

Comment: But `apache poi` attempts creating files for `Microsoft Office` and not `OpenOffice.org`. For `XWPF` tables usable in `OpenOffice.org` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44714666/open-office-writer-crashed-when-inserting-table-using-java-poi/44722587#44722587

Comment: So, because I don't have Microsoft Office installed I'm not going to see the results I want?

Comment: Have you tried setting `TblGrid` as suggested in my linked answer?

Comment: Yeah i did. It aligns it correctly but the actual table borders still dont appear.

Comment: Then please update your question. Show your current used code. Also show the result as a screen-shot. And please describe your environment - which operating system and which word-processing application is used.