# XWPF Columns out of docx document boundaries (Ubuntu 16.04 host)

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi, ubuntu-16.04, libreoffice

I'm running a 4.10.0-42-generic Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with LibreOffice  v5.1.6.2.
Using Oxygen Eclipse 4.7.2, by creating a Maven project, adding poi and poi-ooxml 3.15 as dependencies, I'm trying to create a table using Java in .docx format.
Needless to say, I couldn't find a solution. My code snippet goes like this:

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("samplefile.docx");

   XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

   // New 2x2 table
    XWPFTable tableOne = document.createTable();
    XWPFTableRow tableOneRowOne = tableOne.getRow(0);
    tableOneRowOne.getCell(0).setText("Hello");
    tableOneRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("World");

    XWPFTableRow tableOneRowTwo = tableOne.createRow();
    tableOneRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("This is");
    tableOneRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("a table");

    // Add a break between the tables
    document.createParagraph().createRun().addBreak();

    // New 3x3 table
    XWPFTable tableTwo = document.createTable();
    XWPFTableRow tableTwoRowOne = tableTwo.getRow(0);
    tableTwoRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
    tableTwoRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
    tableTwoRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");

    XWPFTableRow tableTwoRowTwo = tableTwo.createRow();
    tableTwoRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
    tableTwoRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
    tableTwoRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");

    XWPFTableRow tableTwoRowThree = tableTwo.createRow();
    tableTwoRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
    tableTwoRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
    tableTwoRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");

    document.write(fos);
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("Success!");
   }
}
```

The code above displays the following result: 
[image: Sample picture from LibreOffice]

I was wondering whether the problem is in LibreOffice or in my code.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible creating `*.xlsx` files having tables which `LibreOffice` `Writer` also can open properly. But Libreoffice/Openoffice needs a table grid to accept the column widths.

This should work:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordTable {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

      //create table
      XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

      //create first row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
      tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
      tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
      tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");

  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the 3 columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //values are in unit twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch)
  //first column = 2 inches width
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
  //other columns (2 in this case) also each 2 inches width
  for (int col = 1 ; col < 3; col++) {
   table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*1440));
  }

      //create second row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
      tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
      tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
      tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");

      //create third row
      XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();
      tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
      tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
      tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  document.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTable.docx"));
  document.close();

  System.out.println("CreateWordTable written successully");
 }
}
```

See also [Open office writer crashed when inserting table using java POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44714666/open-office-writer-crashed-when-inserting-table-using-java-poi/44722587#44722587).

Answer (score 0):

As I've tried getting the file on a virtual Windows 10 machine, running Microsoft Office, the graphics were displayed properly, thus I assume that LibreOffice cannot handle the lines properly and displays text only.

Issue solved for me - next time I'm testing all my files under Microsoft Office and Windows.

Comment: No need giving up that fast. See my answer. Hint: `*.docx` files are `ZIP` archives containing `XML` files. So we can creating `*.docx` using `LibreOffice` and then unzip them and have a look at the `XML` to determine how `LibreOffice` stores things.

Comment: I've used the code you provided above, but it seems like LibreOffice does not visualize the items as it should. Furthermore - if I convert the *.docx* in *.pdf*, the lines are visualized in the viewer in Windows and Linux. This problem is not present in Windows, Microsoft Office, though. Since the majority of people are using Windows and no document is getting out in *.docx*, but rather in *.pdf*, I don't intend to dig deep in the way how LibreOffice does its magic in visualizing the content. Thank you, @AxelRichter, for your answer!